# How can I set the home button in the middle of the bottom bar to the default value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I made a bottom bar using the DefaultTabController, but the home button was set to the middle. By the way, the default value is on the menu. How can I change the default value to the home button?

this is main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contact/widgets/bottom_bar.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "flutter_project",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),

      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(),
              Container(),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Bottom(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone, please help me

this is bottom_bar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Bottom extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      child: Container(
        height: 70,
        child: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.amber,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          tabs: const <Widget>[
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                size: 18,
              ),
              child: Text(
                  'menu',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 18,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'home',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person_outline,
                size: 18,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'user',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think I need to use the index, but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Use [initialIndex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DefaultTabController/initialIndex.html) in `DefaultTabController`.